# How to enable Claim Tokens in Solidity Smart Contract?

Tags: token, blockchain, solidity, erc20

I am currently using the Open Zapeline smart contract for my Dapp, I wanted to know if there is a way where users can claim my tokens (i.e transfer from owner wallet to current user) I know a method with hardcoding the private keys but is there any way wherein the Smart Contract I can set msg.Sender as Owner or Transfer tokens from Owner account to the user without any signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `internal` function `_transfer()` ([GitHub link](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.4.2/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L327)) that only validates is the `from` param is the actual owner of the token. But it doesn't validate if the `msg.sender` is the token owner.

Note that this function has `internal` visibility, so it's only executable from inside of your contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyCollection is ERC721, Ownable {

    constructor() ERC721("MyCollection", "MyC") {
        _mint(owner(), 1);
    }

    function claim() external {
        require(ownerOf(1) == owner(), "Already claimed");
        _transfer(owner(), msg.sender, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you tell me what do you mean by inside your contract? Can I not use it with the Web3 and call as a Javascript function?

Comment: @HarshitChari Cannot execute it directly from other contracts and offchain apps (such as web3) because of its `internal` visibility. But you can execute the `claim()` wrapper function from a JS app since it's `external`. See the docs about [visibility and getters](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) for more info.

Comment: This solution didn't work actually

Comment: I am trying to build a game where the winner gets rewards in tokens. There is a claim reward button that transfers the token from the owner wallet to the winner wallet. But I am not sure how to send the tokens from the owner wallet with the smart contract claim function.  I am using Open Zepplin ERC-20 smart-contract

Comment: @HarshitChari Can you specify what didn't work? What steps did you take and was there any error message? Using the second snippet in Remix VM emulator, I was able to mint the token ID 1 to the `owner()` address and then claim it from another address - validated with the `ownerOf(1)` function returning first the `owner()` address and then the claimer address.

Comment: I getting an error: The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?

Comment: @HarshitChari There are couple reasons for this. Assuming you implemented the function exactly as in the answer, a most likely reason is that the `owner()` address is not the owner of the token ID 1. Or the token ID 1 doesn't exist. Or the sender address doesn't have sufficient balance to pay for the gas fees. Or there's another issue unrelated to the code if you implemented it in a different way. Please provide steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I was adding the claim () function in my smart contract. Later I tried to implement the exact way of your solution. Both did not work and gave me the same error. Can you please help me out with this as I have sufficient balance because I am working on Polygon testnet and have 2 Matic is all my accounts.

Comment: @HarshitChari Sorry, I'm unable to reproduce your issue as it's working correctly on my end (with the only difference that I'm running in in the Remix VM emulator instead of Polygon testnet). Try to find and describe steps to reproduce the issue step by step on a different account or machine so that I and other answerers can help better.

Comment: Can you tell me more details about what network you are running the above code on? I am always get insufficient gas code error and cannot claim the tokens.

Comment: @HarshitChari Remix VM emulator.